# Migrate firebase anonymous login to permanent account scenario

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an app that can be used anonymously for as long as the user chooses. I use the identifier from the anonymous user to save the user's history, credits, and profile values. Should the user choose to sign up I call the link function the link the provider to the anon account.

My flow is as follows:

1. A new user downloads and opens the app, we check if the user is signed in anonymously, if he is, continue. If he is not signed in we sign him in automatically in the background.
2. Later A user decides to sign up, we sign the user up with one of the providers and link the user to the anon credential
3. The user can now log into his account on any device, and see his history and profile values

My question is how do you manage/migrate a user that was using the app anonymously, who moves to a new device without signing up first?

Ex.
I use the app as is, not signing up. I do transactions, buy credits, and update my profile. I never choose to actually sign up. I just use the app.

I get a new phone and download the app, because it's a new phone I get signed in anon automatically. Once the app starts up I see my history/profile values/credits are blank.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how do you manage/migrate a user that was using the app anonymously, who moves to a new device without signing up first?

There is no way you can do that. As soon as a user signs in anonymously on a new device, a completely new Firebase Anonymous account is created. There is no way you can link two different anonymous accounts that exist on two different devices into a single one.

> I use the app as is, not signing up. I do transactions, buy credits, and update my profile. I never choose to actually sign up. I just use the app.

The only option that you have, is to link the anonymous account on the first device with a provider. In this way, it doesn't matter how many devices the user uses, in the end, you'll always have a single (real) account. So you should encourage them to convert the anonymous account into a real account.

> Once the app starts up I see my history/profile values/credits are blank.

That's the expected behavior since when you authenticate your users in Firebase anonymously, a new UID is generated. So on the second device, you're reading brand-new data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Alex, i understand the mechanics behind it. But are looking for a way to bypass it automatically. I will see how i can convey they the user need to link first

Comment: You're very welcome, Theuno. So can I help you with other information?